# How to reduce waiting time for tcp connection?

Tags: c#, exception, tcp

I use TCP connection to send different messages between two applications. And when you try to send message to another app and this app is not launched, app throwing an exception. Sometimes it takes 10 seconds before throw an exception. How can i reduce this time to 2-3 seconds ?

This is code for sender:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
NetworkStream ns;
client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip_address), port));
string str;
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
sw.AutoFlush = true;
sw.WriteLine(str);
client.Close();
```

And this is code for reciever:

```
TcpListener listner = new TcpListener(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(local_ipAddress), port));
listner.Start();
TcpClient client = listner.AcceptTcpClient();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
string str = sr.ReadLine();
client.Close();
```

Comment: Are these applications on the same machine? If so, it certainly shouldn't take that long... can you provide a [mcve] of how you're communicating?

Comment: Jon, no it on different machines. You mean example of code ?

Comment: Look into the `keepalive` property of a TCP connection, reducing that could affect performance but might help your specific case.

Comment: Yes, a code example would be helpful. If the other machine isn't listening on the port, I'd expect trying to connect to fail quickly - unless they have a firewall which is trying to block port scanning...

Comment: Jon, i'm sorry, i couldn't add code to comment section, so i add it in the question. Can you please look at it ?

Comment: Keyur, can you please tell me where can i find this `keepalive` property?

Comment: you need a timeout

Comment: active92, i thought about it too, but i'm not really understand how to do that. So I'm starting to send message and then parallel start timer, if message didn't come for 3 seconds than break it. But how break it ? What should i do at that moment ?

Comment: @Ramon use ns.ReadTimeOut = 3000; It will automatically break if it reaches 3 seconds.

Comment: @active92, ah, sadly, but i just spotted that i didn't use `NetworkStream ns;` anywhere, so, i can't use this method cause it's arguing that i didn't assign any value to ns.

Comment: @Ramon oh. sorry. did not see that. I can see that you're using streamwriter. checkout sw.writetimeout.

Comment: @active92, sorry, that i'm still bothering you, but i couldn't find `writetimeout` method at ` streamwriter`.

Comment: 10 seconds does not make a lot of sense.  It should be around 45 seconds.  TCP timeouts are not in any way related to what machine or application you connect to, it is always a worst-case selection so connecting to a machine in Timbuktu still works.  TCP does not have a time machine to guess how long it supposed to take.  Reducing it from the default is not an option either, you can only make it longer.